# Swift tableHeaderView autolayout issue

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I'm pretty much stuck with this issue for sometime now.
I'm using a **custom view (CollectionView) as a** **tableHeaderView** (the blue rectangle) and I want to add some margins around using autolayout but nothing seems to work

I have tried

```
  NSLayoutConstraint(item: homeCarousel, attribute: .topMargin, 
     relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .topMargin, 
     multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20).isActive = true
 ------
  homeCarousel.topAnchor.cons.....
```

[image: detailimage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add margin to UITableView's header view directly. Use simple UIView as a container (purple view) and nest the CollectionView (green one) inside of it. Then you will be able to set constraints using a storyboard or in code.

[See screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMStu.jpg)